# String type timestamp to datetime conversion in Python with timezone

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, utc

I want to convert a timestamp in a string format which I get out of a pandas dataframe to a timestamp in datetime format in order to be able to compare it to another timestamp (also in string format) from another dataframe (they should be the same but I know on some lines they are different).

My timestamps are stored in a dataframe called `df`
so `df.loc[:,'Timestamp'].values[0]` is my first timestamp in the dataframe

My timestamp comes in the format: `'29.06.2019 22:00:00 +00:00'`.

I tried the following and got this error:

```
In[]: datetime.strptime(df.loc[:,'Timestamp'].values[0], '%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S %z')
Out[]: ValueError: time data '29.06.2019 22:00:00 +00:00' does not match format '%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S %z'
```

Then I found that it needs to be in the format `'29.06.2019 22:00:00 +0000'`. Which I managed to get when I apply:

```
In[]: newtimestamp = df.loc[:,'Timestamp'].values[0][0:-3]+df.loc[:,'Timestamp'].values[0][-2:]
Out[]: '29.06.2019 22:00:00 +0000'
```

When trying again with `datetime.strptime` I get the exact same error.

```
In[]: datetime.strptime(newtimestamp, '%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S %z')
Out[]: ValueError: time data '29.06.2019 22:00:00 +0000' does not match format '%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S %z'
```

Can anyone maybe help? I don't find anything helping.
If there is an easier way to compare the two timestamps as strings directly I would also appreciate it.

Comment: first, you might want to use [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) if working with pandas and second, use correct parsing directive %Y for 4-digit year, e.g. `pd.to_datetime('29.06.2019 22:00:00 +00:00', format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S %z')`.

Comment: Thanks that helped

Comment: Ok glad that solved your problem. Voting to close as typo.